# Does multiple encryption cycles (using the same password for each iteration) offer any security?

Tags: encryption, aes, 3des

Does running a plaintext through AES multiple times with the same password offers any security benefit akin to triple DES?

Note that I'm assuming “same password for each iteration”.

Comment: Related (yet not exactly the same scenario as those limit themselves to a single encryption pass using more rounds): [More rounds after AES related key attack?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/30921/12164) and/or [Increase number of rounds for SPN and Feistel ciphers](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5050/12164)

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/8119/6417 gives a nice answer for "why did they pick 10 rounds to begin with anyway?" question. I have no idea if a meet in the middle attack would be a thing if the two keys were the same.

Comment: quite interesting read! But do you all think if i should run the iteration at least 5 times or just let it be?

Comment: "... any security benefit akin to triple DES" First, DES does not offer any security, if the same key is used in triple DES. Actually, that is just equal to simple DES. Also, the word *password* is quite wrong. An encryption method requires a key (chosen uniform from the entire keyspace), not a low entropy password, which might in the worst case be chosen by a human user.